# Showing fields via lwc, all fields showing but SRP is not

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable

problem: All fields are showing in the data table but SRP is not.
what i tried to do to solve the isse:  i tried to put a console log to show SRP__c inside the promise but it says it is undefined. Im stuck because all the other fields are showing but srp is not. I have also browsed the documentation for lightning-datatable and for currency I have specified the currency code. I have also checked the fieldname in salesforce itself and its SRP__c.

[image]

[image]

my column code that has the fields of car object that I want to show

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getCarData from '@salesforce/apex/DataController.fetchCar';

const carCol = [{
        label: 'Car Name',
        fieldName: 'CarRecord',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {
                fieldName: 'CarName'
            }
        }
    },{
        label: 'Category',
        fieldName: 'Category',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'Control',
        fieldName: 'Control__c',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'Description',
        fieldName: 'Description__c',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'Fuel Type',
        fieldName: 'Fuel_Type__c',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'Make',
        fieldName: 'Make__c',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'Number of seats',
        fieldName: 'Number_of_Seats__c',
        type: 'number',
    },{
        label: 'SRP',
        fieldName: 'SRP__c',
        type: 'currency',
        typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'USD'},
    },
    
]


export default class CarManufacturing_SHOW extends LightningElement {
    carPicture
    columnCar = carCol
    result
    error

    handleCarData(){
        getCarData().then(res=>{
            let finalData = []
            res.forEach(row=>{
                let objectStruct = {};
                objectStruct.Id = row.Id
                objectStruct.CarName = row.Name
                objectStruct.Category = row.Category__c
                objectStruct.Control__c = row.Control__c
                objectStruct.Description__c = row.Description__c
                objectStruct.Fuel_Type__c = row.Fuel_Type__c
                objectStruct.Make__c = row.Make__c
                objectStruct.Number_of_Seats__c = row.Number_of_Seats__c
                objectStruct.Picture_URL__c = row.Picture_URL__c
                objectStruct.SRP__c = row.SRP__c
                objectStruct.CarRecord = 'https://carlwc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Car__c/'+row.Id+'/view'
                finalData.push(objectStruct)
            });
            this.result = finalData
        }).catch(err=>{
            this.err = err
            console.error(err)
        })
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.handleCarData();
    }
```

this is my html code

```
<template>
   <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
        <lightning-tab label="Show Car Records">
            <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={result}
            columns={columnCar}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Car Model">

        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Campaign">
            
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Car Bookings">
            
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Cases">
            
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Accounts">
            
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Show Contacts">
            
        </lightning-tab>
   </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

my apex class code

```
public with sharing class DataController {
    public DataController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<Car__c> fetchCar(){
        return [SELECT Name,Category__c,Control__c,Description__c,Fuel_Type__c,Make__c,Number_of_Seats__c,Picture_URL__c,SRP__c FROM Car__c];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you query srp in getcardata? Whatever comes from apex class return is shown here.

Comment: hello user 61140, yes I did. I've edited my post and added my apex class

Comment: Put a debug in your apex and see what's in the list?

Comment: hello user, this is what it returned unfortunately its returning the SRP field but in ID why is that? 14:21:30:086 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|(Car__c:{Name=Ford ecosport, Category__c=SUV, Control__c=Automatic, Description__c=Lorem Ipsum book. , Fuel_Type__c=Diesel, Make__c=Ford, Number_of_Seats__c=4, Picture_URL__c=/resource/1659062772000/carhub_images/ford_ecosport.png, Id=a005i000006t6HOAAY}, Car__c:{Name=

Comment: Nope, thats Id. Which means srp is empty. Update a record and re-check

Comment: hmm it suddenly appeared after i updated a record. Salesforce is mysterious or maybe its just the caching that takes too long, I have disabled some cahce session settings for testing as I read in some forum ... thanks user 61140!